# FairPlay offline playback does not work on iOS 10

Tags: ios, avfoundation, drm, fairplay

We are using EZDRM for DRM protection.

Online playback works fine on iOS 10-13, whereas offline playback works on iOS 11-13, but not iOS 10; persistent content key was introduced in iOS 10, so it should work.

I have used EZDRM's sample project to test, which uses `AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate`. After downloading the video and content key, when we tried to play the downloaded video, the following errors occurred.

```
Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11800 "The operation could not be completed" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x17005d1c0 {Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-42651 "(null)"}, NSLocalizedFailureReason=An unknown error occurred (-42651), NSLocalizedDescription=The operation could not be completed}
```

```
Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11800 "The operation could not be completed" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x17005be40 {Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-12882 "(null)"}, NSLocalizedFailureReason=An unknown error occurred (-12882), NSLocalizedDescription=The operation could not be completed}
```

Logging the loading request object (from iOS 10):

```
<AVAssetResourceLoadingRequest: 0x174201f10, URL request = <NSMutableURLRequest: 0x1702009a0> { URL: skd://fps.ezdrm.com/;xxxxxx }, request ID = 2, content information request = <AVAssetResourceLoadingContentInformationRequest: 0x174202060, content type = "(null)", content length = 0, byte range access supported = NO, disk caching permitted = NO, renewal date = (null)>, data request = <AVAssetResourceLoadingDataRequest: 0x174201de0, requested offset = 0, requested length = 9223372036854775807, requests all data to end of resource = YES, current offset = 0>>
```

I found that:

- `disk caching permitted = NO` on iOS 10
- `disk caching permitted = YES` on iOS 11-13

Not sure if it is the reason of failure, and don't know which part controls the value of this property.

I have also used Apple's HLSCatalogWithFPS to test, which uses `AVContentKeySession`. Originally, its deployment target is iOS 11.3, I've modified a bit so that it can also run on iOS 10.3, e.g.:

- `keyRequest.respondByRequestingPersistableContentKeyRequestAndReturnError()` -> `keyRequest.respondByRequestingPersistableContentKeyRequest()`
- `AVAggregateAssetDownloadTask` -> `AVAssetDownloadTask`

However, after calling `respondByRequestingPersistableContentKeyRequest()`, `contentKeySession:didProvidePersistableContentKeyRequest:` did not get called, instead `contentKeySession:didProvideContentKeyRequest:` was called, and it created an infinite loop here.

According to the document https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcontentkeyrequest/2799207-respondbyrequestingpersistableco :

> An NSInternalInconsistencyException is returned if your delegate does not respond to contentKeySession:didProvidePersistableContentKeyRequest:.

So I tried to comment out that delegate method, but there was no exception at all; there was exception if it was running on iOS 11.

It seems the whole FairPlay offline playback thing does not work on iOS 10. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

In EZDRM's **iOS Offline [Example](http://www.ezdrm.com/downloads/fps-ios-demo-updates-3.zip)** they're using the **iOS11** as a base version. This is not a coincidence, it only supports **iOS11 and above**.

> persistent content key was introduced in iOS 10, so it should work

That's not all about the persistent content key, they added more after that, for instance, they added the AVContentKeySession at the iOS version 10.3, etc. I'm not sure if EZDRM supports that but that's important progress in SDK.

Companies can support stable versions only. I'm not sure they specific reason but I can understand. I never used EZDRM's SDK.

Also, please check the documentation: https://www.ezdrm.com/Documentation/EZDRM_Testing_Playback_v2.pdf

Best.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I understand that sometimes it is troublesome to support old OS in which some features are not that stable. My problem is not about EZDRM, I've also used Apple's HLSCatalogWithFPS sample as mentioned in my question. I've tried AVContentKeySession, which was introduced in iOS 10.3, but the respondByRequestingPersistableContentKeyRequest() was not working as expected on a iOS 10.3 device, that's the main problem.